# Show progessbar on page load

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, progress-bar

I have created the script of downloading an facebook album in php. When I will click on download button, script is fetching all photos in that album behind the scene and zip them inside a folder. I want to start a “progress bar” as soon as user-click download button as download process may take time.

Following is `index.php`

```
if ($album['count'] != "0 photos") 
{
   echo "<a href=\"download.php?id={$album['id']}\" title='Download this Album'  class='downloadbtn'><img src=\"common/images/download_button (1).png\"></a>";
}
```

Here I am passing album id to the `download.php`

and following is the code for `download.php` where I am downloading images into the downloads folder, creating the zip file of all that images and downloading that zip file.

```
<?php
require 'facebook/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            'cookie' => true,
        ));

//GETTING THE ID HERE FROM INDEX.PHP FILE

$albumid = $_GET['id'];
$photos = $facebook->api("/{$albumid}/photos?limit=50");

$file_name = rand(1, 99999) . "_image.zip";
$albumArr = array();
foreach ($photos['data'] as $photo) {
    $albumArr[] = $photo['source'];
}

create_zip($albumArr, $file_name);

function create_zip($files, $file_name, $overwrite = false) {
    $i = 0;
    $imgFiles = array();
    foreach ($files as $imglink) {
        $img = @file_get_contents($imglink);
        $destination_path = 'downloads/' . time() . "Image_" . $i . '.jpg';
        @file_put_contents($destination_path, $img);
        $imgFiles[] = $destination_path;
        $i++;
    }

    if (file_exists($file_name) && !$overwrite) {
        return false;
    }
    $valid_files = array();
    if (is_array($imgFiles)) {
        foreach ($imgFiles as $file) {
            $valid_files[] = $file;
        }
    }

    if (count($valid_files)) {

        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        if ($zip->open($file_name, $overwrite ? ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE : ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== true) {
            echo "Sorry ZIP creation failed at this time";
        }
        $size1 = 0;
        foreach ($valid_files as $file) {
            $size1+= filesize($file);
            $zip->addFile($file, pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_BASENAME));
        }

        $zip->close();

        $allimages = glob('downloads/*.jpg');

        foreach ($allimages as $img) { // iterate images
            if (is_file($img)) {
                unlink($img); // delete images
            }
        }

        $count = $zip->numFiles;
        $resultArr = array();
        $resultArr['count'] = $count;
        $resultArr['destination'] = $file_name;

        $filename = $file_name;
        $filepath = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';
        $path = $filepath . $filename;

        if (file_exists($filename)) {
            // push to download the zip
            header('Content-type: application/zip');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
            readfile($filename);
            unlink($filename);
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

I want to start a “progress bar” as soon as user-click download button as download process may take time.

How can I do this? Thanks

Comment: So you want JQuery to perform an asynchronous AJAX call to get the data, and you just display a loading animation whilst your PHP is getting this data and passing it back to the AJAX. Once the AJAX success() function starts, you remove the loading animation and display all your data.

Comment: As for the progress bar, you can use twitter's bootstrap progress bar (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#progress) and set the width % of this to the number you get back from your AJAX call to the PHP. In your PHP is where you need to figure out your percentage and echo it out for the AJAX repeatedly until at 100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? PLease tell me if I didn't understand your question

HTML:

```
 <img id="loadingImage" src="pathToImage" alt="" style="display:none" />
 //pathToImage is the path to where your image is located
```

jQuery:

```
$('#YourButtonID').click(function(){
    $('#loadingImage').css('display','block');
    //call your download page
    return false;
});
```

After your download and redirect are finished, call this method to hide the progressbar

```
    $('#loadingImage').css('display','none');
```

Comment: Its showing the progress bar but not redirecting it to the desired page.

Comment: I am an asp.net guy..I know nothing about PHP.. I can only show you the way.. You should cal the second script (display:none) at the time after your download and redirect have been called..

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using ajax.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("#download_button").click(function() {
     document.getElementById('progressbar').style.display='';
     //call your download page.
  });
});
```